# pygame pong: spawn new ball after a player scored

Tags: python, pygame

I wish to learn how to restart/spawn a new ball to continue the game. When one of the players scores a point - the game finishes as no new ball is made/spawned? Which code do I need to continue the game after each point?

My code for the pong game:

```
    import pygame, sys
    import random
    import math
    pygame.init()

    #Screen Width/Height
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

    #Background Image
    background_image = pygame.image.load("tennis.jpg").convert()

    #Score Font
    pygame.font.init()
    font = pygame.font.Font("Bombing.TTF", 50)

    #Graphics Font
    graphicsScore = "Game Score!"
    graphicsFont = pygame.font.Font("Bombing.TTF", 50)

    #Paddle Player1
    paddle_player1 = pygame.Rect(5,50,5,60)
    player1Score = 0

    #Paddle Player2
    paddle_player2 = pygame.Rect(790,50,5,60)
    player2Score = 0

    #Ball
    ball = pygame.Rect(300,200,20,20)
    ballAngle = math.radians(0)
    ballSpeed = 10
    ballDirection = -1

    #frame
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    #Process Player Input
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

                timeChange = pygame.time.get_ticks() - totalTime
                totalTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()

            player1_up = pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_w] 
            player1_down = pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_s]

            player2_up = pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_UP]
            player2_down = pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_DOWN]

    #Updating Game State Logic
            if player1_up:
                paddle_player1.y += -50 
            if player1_down:
                paddle_player1.y += 50 
            if player2_up:
                paddle_player2.y += -50 
            if player2_down:
                paddle_player2.y += 50 

           if paddle_player1.y < 0:
                paddle_player1.y = 0
           if paddle_player2.y < 0:
                paddle_player2.y = 0

           if paddle_player1.y > screen.get_height() - paddle_player1.height:
                paddle_player1.y = screen.get_height() - paddle_player1.height
            if paddle_player2.y > screen.get_height() - paddle_player2.height:
                paddle_player2.y = screen.get_height() - paddle_player2.height


    #Update Ball
        ball.x += ballDirection * ballSpeed * math.cos(ballAngle)
        ball.y += ballDirection * ballSpeed * math.sin(ballAngle)
        if ball.x > 800 or ball.x < 0:
            ballSpeed *= 1
            if ball.x > 800:
                player1Score = 1
                applause = pygame.mixer.music.load('applause.wav')
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
            if ball.x < 0:
                player2Score = 1
                applause = pygame.mixer.music.load('applause.wav')
                pygame.mixer.music.play()

        if player1Score >= 10 or player2Score >= 10:
                   player1Score = 0
                   player2Score = 0

    #Paddle Collision
        if ball.colliderect(paddle_player1):
                if ball.x < 5:
                    ballDirection *= -1
                    ballAngle = random.randrange(20, 300)

                    pong = pygame.mixer.music.load('serve.wav')
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
        if ball.colliderect(paddle_player2):
                if ball.x > 40:
                    ballDirection *= -1
                    ballAngle = random.randrange(20, 300)

                    pong = pygame.mixer.music.load('serve.wav')
                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    #Wall Collision
        if ball.y <= 0:
            ballAngle *= -1
        if ball.y >= 600:
            ballAngle *= -1


   #Rendering
        screen.blit(background_image, [0,0])
        screen.blit(font.render(str(player1Score), 1, (178,34,34)),(200, 25))
        screen.blit(font.render(str(player2Score), 1, (178,24,24)),(600, 25))
        screen.blit(font.render(str(graphicsScore), 1, (245,255,250)), (330, 25))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0), paddle_player1)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0), paddle_player2)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,255,0), ball)

        clock.tick(50)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: I recommend accepting an edit which fixes your slightly off indentation.

Comment: Check if the ball has left the screen and then just reset its position.

Answer (score 0):

A way to quickly add the functionality into your game that you're looking for is just resetting the ball's parameters to what you set them to  before the main game loop.

for example add this function to your game and then call it whenever a player scores:

```
def resetBall():
    ball.rect.x = 300
    ball.rect.y = 200
    ballAngle = math.radians(0)
    ballSpeed = 10
    ballDirection = -1
```

This should simply set everything except the score back to the game start state.